# How do I set a nullable DateTime to null in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to set up a date range filter on my UI, with checkboxes to say whether a DateTimePicker's value should be used, e.g.

```
Dim fromDate As DateTime? = If(fromDatePicker.Checked, fromDatePicker.Value, Nothing)
```

Yet setting `fromDate` to `Nothing` doesn't result in it being set to `Nothing` but to '12:00:00 AM', and the following `If` statement incorrectly executes the filter because `startDate` is not `Nothing`.

```
If (Not startDate Is Nothing) Then
    list = list.Where(Function(i) i.InvDate.Value >= startDate.Value)
End If
```

How do I really ensure `startDate` gets a value of `Nothing`?

Comment: `Nothing` in VB is closer to being `default(T)` in C#, rather than `null`. Note that the two are equivalent for reference types.

Comment: I personally use `New Date` as a magic number that means "No Date".

Comment: Also, your two bits of code seem to mix up `fromDate` and `startDate`

Comment: @SSS `startDate` is a parameter in a method I pass `fromDate` to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The issue is that it's examining the right-hand side of this assignment first, and deciding that it is of type `DateTime` (no `?`). Then performing the assignment.

This will work:

```
Dim fromDate As DateTime? = If(fromDatePicker.Checked, _
                               fromDatePicker.Value, _
                               CType(Nothing, DateTime?))
```

Because it forces the right-hand side's type to be `DateTime?`.

As I said in my comment, [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be more akin to C#'s `default(T)` rather than `null`:

> `Nothing` represents the default value of a data type. The default value depends on whether the variable is of a value type or of a reference type.

Comment: As you said in your comment as well, "the two are equivalent for reference types", and Nullable(Of DateTime) is a reference type, but it looks like the cast trick works, thanks.

Comment: `Nullable(Of DateTime)` is a reference type. However, at the point in time when `Nothing` was being converted, on the right hand side, we have this type information: `If(Boolean,DateTime,<Nothing>)`. Since the return type of `If` has to match the type of one of its expressions, it picked `DateTime`. It *then* converts `Nothing` to a `DateTime` (creating a default `DateTime`), and only *after* that point does it consider the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

With VB.NET and EF 6.X to save null is:

`Dim nullableData As New Nullable(Of Date)`

Comment: I think this is an interesting point, though not sure it's exactly answering the original question ;). Where I'm setting a nullable date to null in VB.NET I'm using `nullableData = New Date?`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Damien_The_Unbeliever's fine answer, using `New DateTime?` also works:

```
Dim fromDate As DateTime? = If(fromDatePicker.Checked, _
                               fromDatePicker.Value, _
                               New DateTime?)
```

You might find that it looks a bit counter intuitive, why perhaps the `CType(Nothing, DateTime?)` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `New Date` as a magic number:

```
Dim fromDate As New Date
If fromDatePicker.Checked Then
  fromDate = fromDatePicker.Value
End If
If fromDate <> New Date Then
  list = list.Where(Function(i) i.InvDate.Value >= fromDate.Value)
End If
```

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `New Date` and `Nothing` being assigned to a `Date` (or `DateTime`) variable? (hint - there isn't one)

Comment: More typing: `Dim fromDate As Date = Nothing`

Comment: `Dim fromDate As Date` is even less typing and has the same observable effects.

Comment: True enough. However, `fromDate = New Date` is a valid comparison, while `fromDate Is Nothing` is not. So for consistency I would encourage consistent use of `New Date`. I also recommend explicitly setting variables to `Nothing` or `New Date` or `0` or `""` to indicate that the uninitialised value is going to be used as a magic number (and to avoid compiler warnings when you hand them as parameters). It's a style preference I guess - makes no difference at the IL level, as you note.

Comment: `fromDate = Nothing` is a valid comparison, and uses one less character :-)

Comment: @SSS Surely we should be moving away from using legacy types/aliases such as `Date`?

Comment: I guess that's a style choice too. As I said before, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

```
        squery = "insert into tblTest values('" & Me.txtCode.Text & "', @Date)"
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(squery, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        If txtRequireDate.Text = "" Then
            cmd.Parameters("@Date").Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters("@Date").Value = txtRequireDate.Text
        End If
```