# Null (?) Operator returns incorrect value when using generic type constructor. VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, generics, nullable

I am experiencing some weird behavior when using Generic Types and null operator. Why does obj2.CurrentDate return a date value that appears to be incorrect when using the ? (short hand). If I long hand the null operator (if) in the property then it returns the correct and expected value. I thought the ? was the equivalent to the if(expression, returnIfTrue, returnIfFalse).

Also, if the generic type constructor is removed, then the null operator works as expected. Why is this?

```
Return If(CurrentObject1 IsNot Nothing, CurrentObject1.MyDate, Nothing) -- Long Hand Returns correct value

Return CurrentObject1?.MyDate --Short Hande - Returns incorrect value
```

1st Console Application - With Generic Type Constructor, CurrentDate is not what is expected.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj1 As New MyObject1 With {.MyDate = CDate("2017-11-13T14:25:00Z")}
        Dim obj2 As New MyObject2(Of MyObject1)(obj1)

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.MyDate)
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.CurrentDate)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Public MustInherit Class MyBaseObject1
   Property MyDate As Date
End Class

Public Class MyObject1
    Inherits MyBaseObject1
End Class

Public Class MyObject2(Of MyObjectType As {MyBaseObject1, New})
    Public Sub New(obj As MyObjectType)
        m_CurrentObject1 = obj
    End Sub

    Private m_CurrentObject1 As MyObjectType = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentObject1 As MyObjectType
        Get
            Return m_CurrentObject1
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentDate As Date?
        Get
            Return CurrentObject1?.MyDate
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Output of Console Application 1

11/13/2017 8:25:00 AM

2/24/0010 4:56:53 AM

2nd Console Application - Without generic type constructor. Works as expected

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj1 As New MyObject1 With {.MyDate = CDate("2017-11-13T14:25:00Z")}
        Dim obj2 As New MyObject2(obj1)

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.MyDate)
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.CurrentDate)

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module

Public MustInherit Class MyBaseObject1
    Property MyDate As Date
End Class

Public Class MyObject1
    Inherits MyBaseObject1
End Class

Public Class MyObject2
    Public Sub New(obj As MyBaseObject1)
        m_CurrentObject1 = obj
    End Sub

    Private m_CurrentObject1 As MyBaseObject1 = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentObject1 As MyBaseObject1
        Get
            Return m_CurrentObject1
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property CurrentDate As Date?
        Get
            Return CurrentObject1?.MyDate
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Output of 2nd console application

11/13/2017 8:25:00 AM

11/13/2017 8:25:00 AM

Comment: You should edit the values it outputs into the question - it would make it more likely to pique someone's interest. I get "24/02/0010 04:56:53" with the code as shown, and if I use `Property MyDate As Date?` I get "01/01/0001 00:28:38"

Comment: Bear in mind that VB's `Nothing` is more akin to C#'s `default(T)` than to its `null`. So, for instance, the *type* of your first expression is `Date`, *not* `Date?`.

Comment: See [Remarkably similar code in question asking about the return type of `IF()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12595889/15498)

Comment: Then why when the generic constructor is removed, then it works as expected? Even though the first expression is Date, and the return type is Date?

Comment: You found a compiler bug, it is not generating proper code for the `CurrentObject1?.MyDate` expression. It generated bad MSIL code, something you can see when you run peverify.exe on the test program. Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) to let them know about it.

Comment: Meanwhile, consider `Return If(CurrentObject1 Is Nothing, Nothing, CurrentObject1.MyDate)` as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the link Hans, I will report. I am also using the long hand version as a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a compiler bug. Will fix it shortly. In the meantime you can use the following workaround:
    DirectCast(CurrentObject1, MyBaseObject1)?.MyDate

Comment: Another victim of this bug [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48824474/17034).  I was wondering where that Roslyn issue might have come from, looks like user #8982039 is actually AlekseyTs.