# How to have a value of NULL for DateTime?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

In my SQL database, I've declared `DpsDate` and `AdmDate` as `DATE`, also I've set them to allow nulls. When I run my application and leave these columns blank, I get this error:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

This is where I'm a bit confused because I've set them to allow nulls so shouldn't the database accept no value? The application works if I set both dates to "01/01/1900". I've tried setting them to "00/00/0000" but I get the same error.

Here's what I have:

```
        If tbNotifyDate.Text = "" Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DpsDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50).Value = "01/01/1900"
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DpsDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50).Value = tbNotifyDate.Text
        End If

        If tbAdmDate.Text = "" Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdmDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50).Value = "01/01/1900"
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdmDate", SqlDbType.Date, 50).Value = tbAdmDate.Text
        End If
```

Comment: You use `DBNull.Value` to represent `NULL` in ADO.NET regardless of the data type.

Comment: Why are you specifying the size of a `date` parameter as 50?  Either use the actual size, zero or don't set the size.  You only need to specify a size for variable-width data types, e.g. `varchar`.  50 is often used in examples because that's the default for `varchar` and the like but to use it for `date` fields is misleading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a nullable DateTime to null in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595775/how-do-i-set-a-nullable-datetime-to-null-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DBNull.Value` to represent `NULL` in ADO.NET.  Things like table adapters and Entity Framework, which are built on top of ADO.NET, can support nullable value types and thus use `Nothing` to represent `NULL` but ADO.NET itself predates nullable value types, so Microsoft had to invent a type specifically for the purpose of representing `NULL`.

I would suggest using the `If` operator to make the code more concise:

```
Dim value As Date

cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdmDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = If(Date.TryParse(tbAdmDate.Text, value),
                                                          value,
                                                          CObj(DBNull.Value))
```

The `CObj` is required because the two possible results of `If` must be the same type and `Date` and `DBNull` are not the same type.  By casting one possible result as type `Object`, they are both interpreted as type `Object` and the compiler is happy.

Note that, as I have written that example, this will save `NULL` if the `TextBox` contains anything that isn't a valid representation of a `Date`.  You can use whatever validation is appropriate in your specific case or, if you've already validated, just check for an empty `TextBox` and use `CDate`.